# Tomcat 9 slow response while application is processing the request in quick time

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am facing slow response issues with Tomcat9. Following are the environment details
Tomcat 9.0.46,
OpneJDK 11.0.11,
Linux - RHEL 3.10.

A Springboot application deployed Tomcat9 is processing a request in quick time (800-900 milliseconds which was calculated on @PostMapping method).. and handing over the response to HttpServlet.. which then recorded as 9-10 secs as response time on localhost_access logs of tomcat. Can someone help me to understand what's happening within tomcat once response is handed over to httpservlet.

Following is trace of Java calsses from an Application performance management tool:
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameWorkServlet:service --> HTTPServlet:service --> Servlet-dispatcherServlet:doService --> Servlet-dispatcherServlet:checkMutipart --> java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport:parkNanos --> jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe:park (2056msecs and it is repeated 4 times which took 9 secs in 'park' state)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To exclude Spring's fault, did you try adding a [`CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging#spring-built-in-request-logging) to the servlet context? This will allow you to measure how much time is spent in Spring's code.

Comment: `Servlet#service` is called as soon as the request headers have been read. Probably it takes the client 9 more seconds to send the body of the request.

Comment: Thank you @PiotrP.Karwasz
Servlet.doDispatch is also called after Servlet.service ... isn't that doDispatch called after tomcat connector receives complete request including body.